# Task is always cleared when goes into background if I launch my app from play market app after install

Tags: android

So the problem is that I have some weird behavior if I launch my app from play market app.

Let's say i have `ActivityA` - main activity and `ActivityB` - some other activity opened from `ActivityB`.

If I launch app from home screen clicking the icon `ActivityA` is launched, I can open `ActivityB`, close the app, reopen it (from home screen) and I will see `ActivityB` which is correct behavior.

Now when I do the same thing but launch my app from play market app, after I reopen the app ( from home screen) `ActivityA` will be launched, but not `ActivityB`
So when I launch app from play market app there is smth wrong happening to the default settings which makes my app don't keep the backstack.

I have tried using `launchMode="singleTop"` or `"singleTask"`, also tried `alwaysRetainTaskState="true"` but none of these helps.

Again when launched from home screen everything is working exactly as expected which makes me wonder if there is anything special to intent from play market?
My goal is to have the same correct behavior when launched from play market.

EDIT: added my manifest ( only deleted other activities and changed names)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.package.example">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.package.example.MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon_frog"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_icon_frog_round"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="@string/fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity android:name="com.package.example.ActivityB"/>

        <activity android:name="com.package.example.ActivityA">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post the Manifest part containing these activities?

Comment: @h8pathak added my manifest